# Set of a sequence density and limit points

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $X \subset \mathbb R$ be a seq. $\{x_n\}$ in $\mathbb R$ that is *dense* in $\mathbb R.$ What is the set of limit points of $\{x_n\}$ ?

Answer part:

So we know that  $X \cap (x_1, x_2) \neq \emptyset $ such that $x_1 < x_2$ from the dense definition. I guess it should be an increasing sequence. What to do next ? Is it to define a subsequence from $x_1's$, $x_2's$ etc. then show that its partial limit is indeed a infinite set of ($x_1$, $x_2$, ... ) ?

Can you help me with this ?

Thanks...

Comment: I am not familiar with the term “partial limits”, but guess that it means the same as “limit points”, or equivalently the set of limits of convergent subsequences?

Comment: Here is a hint, though: If $X$ is dense then not only is $X\cap(a,b)\ne\emptyset$ for all $a<b$, but that set is *infinite*. For if it is finite, then you can find a smaller open subinterval of $(a,b)$ that avoids all those points …

Comment: @Harald For example, for a sequence 1,0,1,0,1,... partial limits set is (1,0) and say sequence is 1,2,3,1,2,3,... its partial limit set contains 1, 2, and 3...

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen which is the same as "the set of limits of convergent subsequences"

Comment: Look at the set of partial limits (limit points) of sequence $(x_n) _{n=1}^\infty  =\left\lbrace {\dfrac{1}{10},\,\dfrac{2}{10},\, \ldots\, \dfrac{9}{10},\, \dfrac{1}{10^2} ,\,\dfrac{2}{10^2},\, \ldots\, \dfrac{99}{10^2},\, \ldots,\, \dfrac{1}{10^n} ,\,\dfrac{2}{10^n},\, \ldots\, \dfrac{10^n-1}{10^n},\, \ldots} \right \rbrace$.

Comment: I've changed "$dense$" for _dense_.

Comment: @M.Strochyk But it does not satisfy the dense definition if I take $9/10$ as $x_8$ and $1/10^2$ as $ x_9$ then $x_8$ > $ x_9$ which contradicts.

Comment: @Analysis In the above definition of *dense* set $X$  $a$ and $b$ not necessary are elements of $X$. Every interval $(a,\,b)\subset [0,\,1] \quad (a<b)$ contains (infinitely many) elements of sequence $(x_n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a\in\mathbb R$ be arbitrary.
Since $X\cap (a,a+1)$ is nonempty, there is an $y_1:=x_n$ where $n$ is minimal with $x_n\in(a,a+1)$.
If you have already found $y_k>a$, use that $X\cap (a,\min\{y_k,a+2^{-k}\})$ is nonempty, hence you can let $y_{k+1}:= x_n$ where $n$ is minimal with $x_n\in(a,\min\{y_k,a+2^{-k}\})$. The sequence $(y_k)$ is a subsequence of the given sequence and it should be obvious that $y_k\to a$.